# Java servlet get url with the parameters

Tags: java, redirect, servlets, authentication

I'am implementing a Login servlet.After the login, i would like to redirect the user on the page he is trying to go. For the moment, I have a function who gets the requestUrl but if some parameters are presents, this function has no sense.

So I would like to know il a function exist for that.

Example :

I try to go -> http://localhost:8081/monSite/Admin/action?parameters=3

I redirect to the login servlet and after the authentication, I would like to redirect to this previous url.

Thanks,

Comment: There is a JEE standard called Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS). Look here for a tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html. If you want to implement the login on your own, you can use a Servlet Filter to check if the user is logged in. If not redirect to your login page and store the original request in the session. After login save the logged in status in the sesssion and get the original URL out of the session object to redirect to that URL.